# Insert file content (with white line and special characters ) in bash variable for insert in oracle table with sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus, bash

I write this simpe test.ksh scipt:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh

TEST=$(cat $1 )
sqlplus -S *****/*****@*****<<- EOF
```

```sql
set define off;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
INSERT INTO DBADOC.TEST
(
        "TEST"
)
 VALUES
(
      q'[ $TEST ]'
)
;
commit;
EOF

exit
```

---

Now if i run it with a simple file (3 lines without special char):

```
./test.ksh /home/oracle/scripts/test.txt
1 row created.


Commit complete.
```

**It runs perfectly.**

If I choose a complex file (with blank lines and special character ), it doesn't work:

```
./test.ksh /home/oracle/scripts/check_free_space_dg.ksh
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# ========..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) NOM..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) GRU..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) DES..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL-Plus doesn't [support hash as a comment character](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/1565925785/ch04s08.html).  You can use these to make comments:

- `REM` or `REMARK` at the beginning of a line
- `--` (double dashes) at the beginning of a line
- or paired `/*` with `*/` for block comment, as seen in C.

Comment: I don't use comment in sqlplus in my test.ksh script. The commented rows (#) are in the file that i want upload in the database

Comment: None of that seems to be in the examples you've pasted in.

Comment: I don't show the content of the uploaded file. check_free_space_dg.ksh is a bash scritp but i used it for test. I have diffent bash files to upload with different content. I can't post here all my shell scripts.

Comment: The commented rows that you want to upload to the database appear to be the problem.  Your shell script looks fine.  Getting the SQL to fit SQL-Plus' idea of what an acceptable comment is seems like the solution.